# Normalization row by row in data set

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to normalize a datasheet between [-1,+1], and this code I wrote can normalize columns by columns. Could you tell me how to normalize rows by rows?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
   import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/-----.csv')
df_max_scaled = df.copy()
for column in df.columns:
df_max_scaled[column] = df_max_scaled[column] /df_max_scaled[column].abs().max()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` with `axis=1` which will process the DF row-by-row:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x/x.abs().max(), axis=1)
```